How to get all projects in Cloud Functions?
When I run the following code in Cloud Functions, I can only get the current project.
    from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3

    client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient()

    # Search projects
    response = client.search_projects(request={"query": ""})
    print([project.name for project in response])

I was able to get a list of all projects using the gcloud projects list command.
How can I get a list of all projects using Cloud functions?
list_projects gives an error with the parent parameter. I'm using a personal GCP account, so I don't think orgnization is relevant, but I'm not sure. Setting the service account to owner didn't work either. I'd like to avoid hard-coding the service account in main.py if possible. I thought it might be the auth scope, but I don't know where to set it.
What I want to do is get all projects every hour and release unused static IPs. I want to release unused static IPs because I'm charged for them.

In addition to Guillaume's answer, you can only see projects you have permission to see. Permission is granted by each non-org project itself via IAM.

Your Cloud Run Functions runs with a service account (runtime service account). It could be the default one or a user-defined one.
Whatever it is, it has permissions, by default on the current projet only. If you grant this service account in another project, or even at the org level, it will be able to get other projects.
So, check  your runtime service account and grant it according to the perimeter to scan.
Note: In addition to project get permission on other project, you will need additional permission to list and remove IPs. If you simply get these roles (about IPs) on your service account for the project you want to scan, the project.get permission will be automatically granted

Edit 1
To know your runtime service account you can go to the revision tab, and then, on the right hand side, in the security section

When you have this service account, go in another project (project picker on the top left), go to the IAM page, and click on Grant Access. In the panel, set your cloud run runtime service account as principal, and add roles to this principal


Thank you. i don't know how to grant this service account in another project, or even at the org level No organization 0. https://i.sstatic.net/6Lbzf.png

If you have "no organisation" you can't grant at organisation level, because you do not have organisation!

I edited my answer with how to grant permission in another project question
